# Counting the biggest degree of node in Neo4j using own stored procedure

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In order to practise and dive deeply into Neo4j internals I decided to implement easy stored procedure to find the biggest degree of node.

I know that it was implemented:

```
call apoc.stats.degrees(null)
```

Strangely enough, I got an error:

> There is no procedure with the name `apoc.stats.degrees` registered
>   for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure
>   name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.

on version `3.2.3`.

However, I am going implement it on my own and understand where I was wrong:
Look at this piece of code:

```
@Procedure(name = "com.maxdemarzi.get_max_degree", mode = Mode.DEFAULT)
@Description("CALL com.maxdemarzi.get_max_degree()")
public Stream<LongResult> GetMaxDegree() {

ResourceIterable<Node> allNodes = db.getAllNodes();
int degree = allNodes.stream().max((Node n1, Node n2)-> n1.getDegree() >= n2.getDegree() ? 0 : 1).get().getDegree();

return Stream.of(new LongResult(Long.valueOf(degree)));
}
```

It always return `0` despite the fact in my graph there is node with degree `5`.

*Each hint which allows to better understand why my code is not ok is welcome!*

Answer (score 0):

Please check apoc-3.2.3.x.jar installed in Neo4j plugins